# overflow: hidden not functioning as expected

Tags: html, css

I have check the answers on the related subject and attempted to adapt some of the items in the suggestions but none seems to help. The intro and question items don't become hidden when placed outside the #myQuiz dimensions and neither do any of the other items. 
   index.html:

```css
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:900|Roboto:400,100);
    body {
      background-color: #fff;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    #myQuiz {
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 400;
      width: 650;
      height: 650px;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      color: #fff;
      background: #bbb url(../images/background.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px;
    }
    #myQuiz h1 {
      font-weight: 100;
      font-size: 2em;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      margin: 0px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 25px;
      left: 36px;
    }
    #myQuiz h1 span {
      display: block;
      font-weight: 900;
      font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
      font-size: 3.2em;
      line-height: 65px;
    }
    #myQuiz h2 {
      font-size: 3em;
      margin: 0px;
      font-weight: 100;
    }
    #myQuiz h3 {
      font-size: 2.4em;
      margin: 0px;
      font-weight: 100;
    }
    #myQuiz p {
      margin: 0px 0px 14px 0px;
    }
    #myQuiz .btn {
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: #c04b01;
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 5px 15px;
      border-radius: 6px;
    }
    /* Intro */
    #myQuiz .intro {
      position: absolute;
      top: 225px;
      left: 660px;
      width: 550px;
    }
    #myQuiz .intro p {
      margin: 0px 0px 40x 0px;
    }
    /* Questions */
    #myQuiz .question {
      width: 550px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 225px;
      left: 650px;
    }
    #myQuiz .question .txt {
      font-size 1.6em;
      margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    }
    #myQuiz .question .ans {
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 1.1em;
      width: 225px;
      border: 2px solid rgba(238, 189, 102, .4);
      border-radius: 6px;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
      position: relative;
    }
    #myQuiz .ans.selected {
      border-color: #be4b16;
    }
    #myQuiz .ans.correct {
      border-color: #459a2e;
    }
    #myQuiz .question .ans::after {
      content: '';
      diplay: block;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      background: no-repeat 0px 0px;
      background-size: 20px 20px;
      position: absolute;
      top 5px;
      right: 5px;
    }
    #myQuiz .question .ans.selected::after {
      background-image: url(../images/icon_incorrect.svg);
    }
    #myQuiz .question .ans.correct::after {
      background-image: url(../images/icon_correct.svg);
    }
    #myQuiz .question.unanswered .ans {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    #myQuiz .question.unanswered .ans:hover {
      background-color: rgba(238, 189, 102, .2);
    }
    #myQuiz .question.answered .ans {
      cursor: default;
    }
    /* Feedback */
    #myQuiz .feedback {
      color: #efbe5e;
      margin-top: 50px;
      transition: opacity 1.5s, margin-top 1.5s;
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    #myQuiz .feedback .btn {
      margin-top: 5px;
    }
    #myQuiz .feedback strong {
      color: #fff;
    }
    #myQuiz .answered .feedback {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-
    8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-
    scale=1">
  <title>Test Your Knowledge: Saturn</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/quiz.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="myQuiz">
    <h1>Test Your Knowledge:<span>Saturn</span></h1>
    <div class="progress"></div>
    <div class="intro">
      <h2>Welcome</h2>
      <p>Click begin to test your knowledge of Saturn</p>
      <p class="btn">Begin</p>
    </div>
    <!--intro-->
    <div class="question answered">
      <p class="txt">This is a question</p>
      <p class="ans">Answer 1</p>
      <p class="ans selected">Answer 2</p>
      <p class="ans correct">Answer 3</p>
      <p class="ans">Answer 4</p>
      <div class="feedback">
        <p>Your are <strong>correct</strong>.</p>
        <p>Oops! That is not correct.</p>
        <p>Addition feedback.</p>
        <div class="btn">Continue</div>
        <!--btn-->
      </div>
      <!--feedback -->
    </div>
    <!--question -->

    <div class="results"></div>

  </div>
  <!-- MyQuiz -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `#myQuiz` you miss the unit for the width, making it invalid and ignored by the browser.

You have

```
width: 650;
```

and it must be

```
width: 650px;
```

```css
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:900|Roboto:400, 100);
    body {
      background-color: #fff;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    #myQuiz {
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 400;
      width: 650px;
      height: 650px;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      color: #fff;
      background: #bbb url(../images/background.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px;
    }
    #myQuiz h1 {
      font-weight: 100;
      font-size: 2em;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      margin: 0px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 25px;
      left: 36px;
    }
    #myQuiz h1 span {
      display: block;
      font-weight: 900;
      font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
      font-size: 3.2em;
      line-height: 65px;
    }
    #myQuiz h2 {
      font-size: 3em;
      margin: 0px;
      font-weight: 100;
    }
    #myQuiz h3 {
      font-size: 2.4em;
      margin: 0px;
      font-weight: 100;
    }
    #myQuiz p {
      margin: 0px 0px 14px 0px;
    }
    #myQuiz .btn {
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: #c04b01;
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 5px 15px;
      border-radius: 6px;
    }
    /* Intro */
    #myQuiz .intro {
      position: absolute;
      top: 225px;
      left: 660px;
      width: 550px;
    }
    #myQuiz .intro p {
      margin: 0px 0px 40x 0px;
    }
    /* Questions */
    #myQuiz .question {
      width: 550px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 225px;
      left: 650px;
    }
    #myQuiz .question .txt {
      font-size 1.6em;
      margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    }
    #myQuiz .question .ans {
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 1.1em;
      width: 225px;
      border: 2px solid rgba(238, 189, 102, .4);
      border-radius: 6px;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
      position: relative;
    }
    #myQuiz .ans.selected {
      border-color: #be4b16;
    }
    #myQuiz .ans.correct {
      border-color: #459a2e;
    }
    #myQuiz .question .ans::after {
      content: '';
      diplay: block;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      background: no-repeat 0px 0px;
      background-size: 20px 20px;
      position: absolute;
      top 5px;
      right: 5px;
    }
    #myQuiz .question .ans.selected::after {
      background-image: url(../images/icon_incorrect.svg);
    }
    #myQuiz .question .ans.correct::after {
      background-image: url(../images/icon_correct.svg);
    }
    #myQuiz .question.unanswered .ans {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    #myQuiz .question.unanswered .ans:hover {
      background-color: rgba(238, 189, 102, .2);
    }
    #myQuiz .question.answered .ans {
      cursor: default;
    }
    /* Feedback */
    #myQuiz .feedback {
      color: #efbe5e;
      margin-top: 50px;
      transition: opacity 1.5s, margin-top 1.5s;
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    #myQuiz .feedback .btn {
      margin-top: 5px;
    }
    #myQuiz .feedback strong {
      color: #fff;
    }
    #myQuiz .answered .feedback {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-
    8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-
    scale=1">
  <title>Test Your Knowledge: Saturn</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/quiz.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="myQuiz">
    <h1>Test Your Knowledge:<span>Saturn</span></h1>
    <div class="progress"></div>
    <div class="intro">
      <h2>Welcome</h2>
      <p>Click begin to test your knowledge of Saturn</p>
      <p class="btn">Begin</p>
    </div>
    <!--intro-->
    <div class="question answered">
      <p class="txt">This is a question</p>
      <p class="ans">Answer 1</p>
      <p class="ans selected">Answer 2</p>
      <p class="ans correct">Answer 3</p>
      <p class="ans">Answer 4</p>
      <div class="feedback">
        <p>Your are <strong>correct</strong>.</p>
        <p>Oops! That is not correct.</p>
        <p>Addition feedback.</p>
        <div class="btn">Continue</div>
        <!--btn-->
      </div>
      <!--feedback -->
    </div>
    <!--question -->

    <div class="results"></div>

  </div>
  <!-- MyQuiz -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Connexo.  That was the answer.  Very grateful.